# A Partial<T> which keeps one field of T as requiered in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Say that we have the interface

```
interface Thing {
  uuid: string;
  edges: number;
  corners: number;
}
```

And you want to implement a type where all but uuid are left as optional properties. Such a type would be useful when passing around changesets to `Thing`s where all things are mapped by their `uuid` in a hashmap.

`Partial<Thing>` makes all the fields of `Thing` optional whis is not what we want, we want `uuid` to remain obligatory.

How would you implement such a type with as little code duplication as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Partial` and `Pick` to achieve the desired effect:

```
type PartialRequired<T, TRequired extends keyof T> = Partial<T> & Pick<T, TRequired>

type PartialThing = PartialRequired<Thing, 'uuid'>

let pp: PartialThing = {
    uuid: ""
}
```

The above version has a minor inconvenience,  `uuid` will have type `string | (undefined & string)` which works as expected but looks bad, we could use an `Omit` type to have a friendlier type:

```
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[P in T]: P } & {[P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];  
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Diff<keyof T, K>>; 
type PartialRequired<T, TRequired extends keyof T> = Partial<Omit<T, TRequired>> & Pick<T, TRequired>
```

The usage is the same.

Also for either version you can specify more required fields:

```
type PartialThingWithEdges = PartialRequired<Thing, 'uuid' | 'edges'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like what I'm after is possible to implement by extending a partial derivative of the interface.

```
interface PartialThing extends Partial<Thing> {
  uuid: string;
}
```

A `PartialThing` is then forced to have a `uuid` but the two remaining fields are left as optional.